# Upgrading asp.net core from 2.1.0 to 2.1.5

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, upgrade

I'd like to upgrade .net core on my website from 2.1.0 to 2.1.5.

My app is using the nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All (2.1.0) and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (2.1.0) which I uninstalled and then replaced with Microsoft.AspNetCore.All (2.1.5) and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (2.1.4).

The app compiles fine but when I run it it fails with:

```
The program '[10808] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450730 (0x80008096).
Verbose logs are written to:
C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-chrome-debug.txt
The program '' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

The contents of the log file are:

```
OS: win32 ia32
Adapter node: v6.4.0 ia32
vscode-chrome-debug-core: 6.7.7
1:07:08 PM, 10/28/2018
debugger-for-chrome: 4.8.2
From client: initialize({"clientID":"visualstudio","clientName":"Visual Studio","adapterID":"chrome","locale":"en-US","linesStartAt1":true,"columnsStartAt1":true,"pathFormat":"path","supportsVariableType":true,"supportsRunInTerminalRequest":true,"supportsHandshakeRequest":true,"supportsMapURLToFilePathRequest":true,"supportsLaunchUnelevatedProcessRequest":true})
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":1,"command":"initialize","success":true,"body":{"exceptionBreakpointFilters":[{"label":"All Exceptions","filter":"all","default":false},{"label":"Uncaught Exceptions","filter":"uncaught","default":false}],"supportsConfigurationDoneRequest":true,"supportsSetVariable":true,"supportsConditionalBreakpoints":true,"supportsCompletionsRequest":true,"supportsHitConditionalBreakpoints":true,"supportsRestartFrame":true,"supportsExceptionInfoRequest":true,"supportsDelayedStackTraceLoading":true,"supportsValueFormattingOptions":true,"supportsEvaluateForHovers":true,"supportsLoadedSourcesRequest":true,"supportsRestartRequest":true,"supportsSetExpression":true,"supportsLogPoints":true}}
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"telemetry","output":"ClientRequest/initialize","data":{"Versions.DebugAdapterCore":"6.7.7","Versions.DebugAdapter":"4.8.2","successful":"true","timeTakenInMilliseconds":"21.930325","requestType":"request"}}}
From client: launch({"noDebug":false,"name":"Attach to Chrome program from Visual Studio","type":"chrome","request":"launch","breakOnLoad":true,"breakOnLoadStrategy":"instrument","_clientOverlayPausedMessage":"Paused in Visual Studio","trace":true,"sourceMaps":true,"showAsyncStacks":true,"smartStep":false,"url":"https://localhost:44346/","runtimeExecutable":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe","runtimeArgs":"","userDataDir":"C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\15.0_0fe76bd1\\WebTools\\ChromeUserData_B1BEBFE6_B40C53F9-A0F2-4A03-9E6B-7ED75B1562AA","webRoot":"C:\\Develop\\Websites\\Paranormal\\Paranormal\\wwwroot","port":52097})
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"telemetry","output":"debugStarted","data":{"Versions.DebugAdapterCore":"6.7.7","Versions.DebugAdapter":"4.8.2","request":"launch","args":["noDebug","name","type","request","breakOnLoad","breakOnLoadStrategy","_clientOverlayPausedMessage","trace","sourceMaps","showAsyncStacks","smartStep","url","runtimeExecutable","runtimeArgs","userDataDir","webRoot","port","pathMapping","sourceMapPathOverrides","skipFileRegExps"]}}}
spawn('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe', ["--remote-debugging-port=52097","--no-first-run","--no-default-browser-check","--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\15.0_0fe76bd1\\WebTools\\ChromeUserData_B1BEBFE6_B40C53F9-A0F2-4A03-9E6B-7ED75B1562AA","about:blank"])
Getting browser and debug protocol version via http://127.0.0.1:52097/json/version
Discovering targets via http://127.0.0.1:52097/json/list
Got browser version: Chrome/70.0.3538.77
Got debug protocol version: 1.3
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"telemetry","output":"targetDebugProtocolVersion","data":{"Versions.DebugAdapterCore":"6.7.7","Versions.DebugAdapter":"4.8.2"}}}
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"telemetry","output":"targetCount","data":{"Versions.DebugAdapterCore":"6.7.7","Versions.DebugAdapter":"4.8.2","numTargets":2}}}
Attaching to target: {"description":"","devtoolsFrontendUrl":"/devtools/inspector.html?ws=localhost/devtools/page/E7890F76DD756B29A4C2FF36774AAF53","id":"E7890F76DD756B29A4C2FF36774AAF53","title":"","type":"page","url":"about:blank","webSocketDebuggerUrl":"ws://127.0.0.1:52097/devtools/page/E7890F76DD756B29A4C2FF36774AAF53"}
WebSocket Url: ws://127.0.0.1:52097/devtools/page/E7890F76DD756B29A4C2FF36774AAF53
→ To target: "{\"id\":1,\"method\":\"Console.enable\"}"
→ To target: "{\"id\":2,\"method\":\"Debugger.enable\"}"
→ To target: "{\"id\":3,\"method\":\"Runtime.enable\"}"
→ To target: "{\"id\":4,\"method\":\"Runtime.runIfWaitingForDebugger\"}"
→ To target: "{\"id\":5,\"method\":\"Runtime.run\"}"
→ To target: "{\"id\":6,\"method\":\"Page.enable\"}"
→ To target: "{\"id\":7,\"method\":\"Network.enable\",\"params\":{}}"
← From target: {"id":1,"result":{}}
← From target: {"id":2,"result":{"debuggerId":"(872A917ED166C84EB9028E8737093920)"}}
← From target: {"method":"Runtime.executionContextCreated","params":{"context":{"id":1,"origin":"://","name":"","auxData":{"isDefault":true,"type":"default","frameId":"E7890F76DD756B29A4C2FF36774AAF53"}}}}
← From target: {"id":3,"result":{}}
← From target: {"id":4,"result":{}}
← From target: {"error":{"code":-32601,"message":"'Runtime.run' wasn't found"},"id":5}
← From target: {"id":6,"result":{}}
← From target: {"id":7,"result":{}}
→ To target: "{\"id\":8,\"method\":\"Debugger.setBlackboxPatterns\",\"params\":{\"patterns\":[\"^chrome-extension:.*\"]}}"
→ To target: "{\"id\":9,\"method\":\"Schema.getDomains\"}"
← From target: {"id":9,"result":{"domains":[{"name":"Inspector","version":"1.2"},{"name":"Memory","version":"1.2"},{"name":"Page","version":"1.2"},{"name":"Emulation","version":"1.2"},{"name":"Security","version":"1.2"},{"name":"Network","version":"1.2"},{"name":"Database","version":"1.2"},{"name":"IndexedDB","version":"1.2"},{"name":"CacheStorage","version":"1.2"},{"name":"DOMStorage","version":"1.2"},{"name":"CSS","version":"1.2"},{"name":"ApplicationCache","version":"1.2"},{"name":"DOM","version":"1.2"},{"name":"IO","version":"1.2"},{"name":"DOMDebugger","version":"1.2"},{"name":"DOMSnapshot","version":"1.2"},{"name":"ServiceWorker","version":"1.2"},{"name":"Input","version":"1.2"},{"name":"LayerTree","version":"1.2"},{"name":"DeviceOrientation","version":"1.2"},{"name":"Tracing","version":"1.2"},{"name":"Animation","version":"1.2"},{"name":"Accessibility","version":"1.2"},{"name":"Storage","version":"1.2"},{"name":"Log","version":"1.2"},{"name":"Runtime","version":"1.2"},{"name":"Debugger","version":"1.2"},{"name":"Profiler","version":"1.2"},{"name":"HeapProfiler","version":"1.2"},{"name":"Schema","version":"1.2"},{"name":"Target","version":"1.2"},{"name":"Overlay","version":"1.2"},{"name":"Performance","version":"1.2"},{"name":"Audits","version":"1.2"},{"name":"HeadlessExperimental","version":"1.2"}]}}
→ To target: "{\"id\":10,\"method\":\"Debugger.setAsyncCallStackDepth\",\"params\":{\"maxDepth\":4}}"
← From target: {"method":"Page.frameResized","params":{}}
← From target: {"id":8,"result":{}}
← From target: {"id":10,"result":{}}
→ To target: "{\"id\":11,\"method\":\"Runtime.evaluate\",\"params\":{\"expression\":\"navigator.userAgent\",\"silent\":true}}"
→ To target: "{\"id\":12,\"method\":\"Browser.getVersion\"}"
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":2,"command":"launch","success":true}
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"telemetry","output":"ClientRequest/launch","data":{"Versions.DebugAdapterCore":"6.7.7","Versions.DebugAdapter":"4.8.2","successful":"true","timeTakenInMilliseconds":"872.118059","requestType":"request","doesHostSupportLaunchUnelevated":"true"}}}
← From target: {"id":12,"result":{"protocolVersion":"1.3","product":"Chrome/70.0.3538.77","revision":"@0f6ce0b0cd63a12cb4eccea3637b1bc9a29148d9","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36","jsVersion":"7.0.276.32"}}
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"telemetry","output":"target-version","data":{"Versions.DebugAdapterCore":"6.7.7","Versions.DebugAdapter":"4.8.2","Versions.Target.CRDPVersion":"1.3","Versions.Target.Revision":"@0f6ce0b0cd63a12cb4eccea3637b1bc9a29148d9","Versions.Target.UserAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36","Versions.Target.V8":"7.0.276.32","Versions.Target.Project":"Chrome","Versions.Target.Version":"70.0.3538.77"}}}
← From target: {"method":"Debugger.scriptParsed","params":{"scriptId":"18","url":"","startLine":0,"startColumn":0,"endLine":0,"endColumn":19,"executionContextId":1,"hash":"3a6f8cb8708878331cc2be2ec90de0ab25738855","executionContextAuxData":{"isDefault":true,"type":"default","frameId":"E7890F76DD756B29A4C2FF36774AAF53"},"isLiveEdit":false,"sourceMapURL":"","hasSourceURL":false,"isModule":false,"length":19}}
→ To target: "{\"id\":13,\"method\":\"Debugger.getPossibleBreakpoints\",\"params\":{\"start\":{\"scriptId\":\"18\",\"lineNumber\":0,\"columnNumber\":0},\"end\":{\"scriptId\":\"18\",\"lineNumber\":1,\"columnNumber\":0},\"restrictToFunction\":false}}"
← From target: {"id":11,"result":{"result":{"type":"string","value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}}}
Target userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36
→ To target: "{\"id\":14,\"method\":\"Network.setCacheDisabled\",\"params\":{\"cacheDisabled\":false}}"
← From target: {"id":13,"result":{"locations":[{"scriptId":"18","lineNumber":0,"columnNumber":0}]}}
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"initialized"}
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"loadedSource","body":{"reason":"new","source":{"name":"VM18","path":"<eval>/VM18","sourceReference":1000}}}
← From target: {"id":14,"result":{}}
From client: setBreakpoints({"source":{"path":"c:\\Develop\\Websites\\Paranormal\\Silverdex.FFMpeg\\FFmpegMediaInfo.cs","sources":[],"checksums":[]},"breakpoints":[{"line":473,"column":13}],"lines":[473]})
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"telemetry","output":"setBreakpointsRequest","data":{"Versions.DebugAdapterCore":"6.7.7","Versions.DebugAdapter":"4.8.2","Versions.Target.CRDPVersion":"1.3","Versions.Target.Revision":"@0f6ce0b0cd63a12cb4eccea3637b1bc9a29148d9","Versions.Target.UserAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36","Versions.Target.V8":"7.0.276.32","Versions.Target.Project":"Chrome","Versions.Target.Version":"70.0.3538.77","fileExt":".cs"}}}
SourceMaps.setBP: c:\Develop\Websites\Paranormal\Silverdex.FFMpeg\FFmpegMediaInfo.cs can't be resolved to a loaded script. It may just not be loaded yet.
Paths.setBP: No target url cached yet for client path: c:\develop\websites\paranormal\silverdex.ffmpeg\ffmpegmediainfo.cs.
→ To target: "{\"id\":15,\"method\":\"DOMDebugger.setInstrumentationBreakpoint\",\"params\":{\"eventName\":\"scriptFirstStatement\"}}"
From client: setBreakpoints({"source":{"path":"c:\\Develop\\Websites\\Paranormal\\Silverdex.FFMpeg\\FFmpegMediaInfo.cs","sources":[],"checksums":[]},"breakpoints":[{"line":473,"column":13}],"lines":[473]})
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"telemetry","output":"setBreakpointsRequest","data":{"Versions.DebugAdapterCore":"6.7.7","Versions.DebugAdapter":"4.8.2","Versions.Target.CRDPVersion":"1.3","Versions.Target.Revision":"@0f6ce0b0cd63a12cb4eccea3637b1bc9a29148d9","Versions.Target.UserAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36","Versions.Target.V8":"7.0.276.32","Versions.Target.Project":"Chrome","Versions.Target.Version":"70.0.3538.77","fileExt":".cs"}}}
From client: setExceptionBreakpoints({"filters":[]})
→ To target: "{\"id\":16,\"method\":\"Debugger.setPauseOnExceptions\",\"params\":{\"state\":\"none\"}}"
SourceMaps.setBP: c:\Develop\Websites\Paranormal\Silverdex.FFMpeg\FFmpegMediaInfo.cs can't be resolved to a loaded script. It may just not be loaded yet.
Paths.setBP: No target url cached yet for client path: c:\develop\websites\paranormal\silverdex.ffmpeg\ffmpegmediainfo.cs.
← From target: {"id":15,"result":{}}
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":3,"command":"setBreakpoints","success":true,"body":{"breakpoints":[{"id":1000,"verified":false,"message":"Breakpoint set but not yet bound"}]}}
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"telemetry","output":"ClientRequest/setBreakpoints","data":{"Versions.DebugAdapterCore":"6.7.7","Versions.DebugAdapter":"4.8.2","Versions.Target.CRDPVersion":"1.3","Versions.Target.Revision":"@0f6ce0b0cd63a12cb4eccea3637b1bc9a29148d9","Versions.Target.UserAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36","Versions.Target.V8":"7.0.276.32","Versions.Target.Project":"Chrome","Versions.Target.Version":"70.0.3538.77","successful":"true","timeTakenInMilliseconds":"8.656402","requestType":"request"}}}
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":4,"command":"setBreakpoints","success":true,"body":{"breakpoints":[{"id":1001,"verified":false,"message":"Breakpoint set but not yet bound"}]}}
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"telemetry","output":"ClientRequest/setBreakpoints","data":{"Versions.DebugAdapterCore":"6.7.7","Versions.DebugAdapter":"4.8.2","Versions.Target.CRDPVersion":"1.3","Versions.Target.Revision":"@0f6ce0b0cd63a12cb4eccea3637b1bc9a29148d9","Versions.Target.UserAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36","Versions.Target.V8":"7.0.276.32","Versions.Target.Project":"Chrome","Versions.Target.Version":"70.0.3538.77","successful":"true","timeTakenInMilliseconds":"4.619639","requestType":"request"}}}
← From target: {"id":16,"result":{}}
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":5,"command":"setExceptionBreakpoints","success":true}
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"telemetry","output":"ClientRequest/setExceptionBreakpoints","data":{"Versions.DebugAdapterCore":"6.7.7","Versions.DebugAdapter":"4.8.2","Versions.Target.CRDPVersion":"1.3","Versions.Target.Revision":"@0f6ce0b0cd63a12cb4eccea3637b1bc9a29148d9","Versions.Target.UserAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36","Versions.Target.V8":"7.0.276.32","Versions.Target.Project":"Chrome","Versions.Target.Version":"70.0.3538.77","successful":"true","timeTakenInMilliseconds":"5.50894","requestType":"request"}}}
From client: configurationDone({})
→ To target: "{\"id\":17,\"method\":\"Page.navigate\",\"params\":{\"url\":\"https://localhost:44346/\"}}"
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":6,"command":"configurationDone","success":true}
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"telemetry","output":"ClientRequest/configurationDone","data":{"Versions.DebugAdapterCore":"6.7.7","Versions.DebugAdapter":"4.8.2","Versions.Target.CRDPVersion":"1.3","Versions.Target.Revision":"@0f6ce0b0cd63a12cb4eccea3637b1bc9a29148d9","Versions.Target.UserAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36","Versions.Target.V8":"7.0.276.32","Versions.Target.Project":"Chrome","Versions.Target.Version":"70.0.3538.77","successful":"true","timeTakenInMilliseconds":"2.013444","requestType":"request"}}}
From client: disconnect({"terminateDebuggee":true})
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can make the upgrade stick?

Comment: is that a beta?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and noticed that I was missing a runtime as indicated in your log above. The fix is to make sure you have the correct .Net Core SDK/runtimes installed
[Installed .Net Core SDK/runtimes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9arHX.png)